Python Kubernetes MutatingWebhook Not Adding Labels
I have created a Kubernetes MutatingWebhook using a Docker image I built from Python.  The purpose of the webhook is to add labels to any Pod that is launched.  All Kubernetes resources are running fine, however, when new Pods are launched they do not get the expected labels from the MutatingWebhook.
I get this error when I launch a new Pod:
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "add-labels.k8s.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://add-labels-webhook-svc.mutatingwh.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.3.33.250:443: connect: connection refused

Here is the Python webhook code:
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/mutate', methods=['POST'])
def mutate():
    # Read the admission review request
    admission_review = request.get_json()
    print("AdmissionReview Request:", json.dumps(admission_review))

    # Define the patch to add labels
    patch = [
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/live",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/environment",
            "value": "production"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/service",
            "value": "my-service"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/version",
            "value": "7.55.2"
        }
    ]

    # Encode the patch to base64
    patch_base64 = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(patch).encode()).decode()

    # Prepare the admission review response
    admission_response = {
        "uid": admission_review['request']['uid'],
        "allowed": True,
        "patchType": "JSONPatch",
        "patch": patch_base64
    }

    # Return the admission review response
    response = {
        "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1",
        "kind": "AdmissionReview",
        "response": admission_response
    }

    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context=('/tls/tls.crt', '/tls/tls.key'), debug=True)

Here are the various K8s manifest files that I used for the deployment, services, etc.
deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook
  namespace: mutatingwh
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: add-labels-webhook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: add-labels-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webhook
          image: 805960120419.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/noc/add-labels-webhook:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tls-certs
              mountPath: /tls
              readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ecr-secret
      volumes:
        - name: tls-certs
          secret:
            secretName: webhook-tls

service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook-svc
  namespace: mutatingwh
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: add-labels-webhook

mutatingwebhookconfiguration.yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook
webhooks:
  - name: add-labels.k8s.io
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: add-labels-webhook-svc
        namespace: mutatingwh
        path: "/mutate"
      caBundle: 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
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
    sideEffects: None
    rules:
      - operations: ["CREATE"]
        apiGroups: [""]
        apiVersions: ["v1"]
        resources: ["pods"]
    failurePolicy: Fail

My question is why is everything running fine, but when new Pods are created they do not get the labels from the Python webhook?

Kubernetes admission webhooks require the webhook server to use HTTPS. I fixed my problem by generating a TLS certificate and key using the following five openssl commands:
Generate a Private Key for the CA
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
Create a Self-Signed Certificate for the CA
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=MutatingWebhookCA" -days 365 -out ca.crt
Generate the Webhook Server Private Key
openssl genrsa -out webhook-server.key 2048
Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for the Webhook Server
openssl req -new -key webhook-server.key -subj "/CN=add-labels-webhook-svc.mutatingwh.svc" -out webhook-server.csr
Sign the Webhook Server Certificate with the CA
openssl x509 -req -in webhook-server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out webhook-server.crt -days 365 -extfile <(echo "subjectAltName=DNS:add-labels-webhook-svc.mutatingwh.svc")
